# Can 1 debezium container connect to multiple postgres databases?

Tags: postgresql, debezium

Says that I have 3 different Postgres database hosting on a different cloud providers.
So I wonder if I could use 1 Debezium container to connect to these 3 databases to send datas to Kafka ?
If yes, I wonder if there are documents or articles that I can use to reference.

Or do I need to have 3 different Debeizum container for each databases?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need three connectors.
As your DB clusters are different and fir each connector you can specify only one DB host

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).